# Pass dynamic key value pair data from AJAX to controller gives null value

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I try to pass dynamic key value pair data from AJAX controller. Key and Value both are not fixed.

My AJAX call:

```
var lstJson = [];
$('#divjson').find('.jsonKeyValue').each(function(index, element) {
  var key = $(this).find(".key").val();
  var value = $(this).find(".value").val();
  var lst = {};
  lst.key = key;
  lst.value = value;
  lstJson.push(lst);
});
console.log(lstJson);
SecureAjaxCall.PassObject({
  url: `${MyHostURL}/Localization/SaveJsonData`,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: JSON.stringify({
    lstJson: lstJson
  }),
  success: function(data) {
    alert('success');
  }
});
```

Other AJAX parameter's like `dataType: 'json',`, `type: 'POST',`... comes dynamically that's not a problem.

When I see on devtool , It's post data:

```
{
   "lstJson":[
      {
         "key":"create",
         "value":"Banauhos"
      },
      {
         "key":"btnGetstarted",
         "value":"SuruGarnuhos"
      },
      {
         "key":"titleOne",
         "value":"Sirsak1"
      },
      {
         "key":"data",
         "value":"Tathyanka"
      }
   ]
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public string SaveJsonData([FromBody] GetlocalizeValue lstJson)
{
    // Other code to Save data but lstJson gives always null value
    return "Success";
}
```

My getters and setters:

```
 public class GetlocalizeValue
 {
        public List<GetlocalizeValue> lstJson { get; set; }
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string FilePath { get; set; 
 }
```

But I always get null value on my controller (`lstJson` is always null)?  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model must reflect the json object structure:

```cs
public class KeysAndValues
{
    [JsonPropertyName("key")
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("value")
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class LocalizedValues
{
    [JsonPropertyName("lstJson")]
    public KeysAndValues[] ListJson { get; set; }
}
```

> It is recommended to follow c# property naming conventions by capitalizing the first letters, and provide a property name for json.

Comment: Modify the method accept a string parameter, then deserialize it to `LocalizedValues` object.

Comment: Can you elaborate more and put that as an answer , sorry I don't understand.

Comment: your method is accepting an object of type `GetlocalizeValue`, but youare actually sending a `string` from json